# How to find daily differences over a flexible time period?

Tags: sql, sql-server, olap-cube

I have a very set of data as follows:

```
CustomerId     char(6)
Points         int
PointsDate     date
```

with example data such as:

```
000021   0   01-JAN-2014
000021  10   02-JAN-2014
000021  20   03-JAN-2014
000021  30   06-JAN-2014
000021  40   07-JAN-2014
000021  10   12-JAN-2014
000034   0   04-JAN-2014
000034  40   05-JAN-2014
000034  20   06-JAN-2014
000034  40   08-JAN-2014
000034  60   10-JAN-2014
000034  80   21-JAN-2014
000034  10   22-JAN-2014
```

So, the `PointsDate` component is NOT consistent, nor is it contiguous (it's based around some "activity" happening)

I am trying to get, for each customer, the total amount of positive and negative differences in points, the number of positive and negative changes, as well as Max and Min...but ignoring the very first instance of the customer - which will always be zero.

e.g.

```
CustomerId  Pos  Neg  Count(pos) Count(neg) Max  Min
000021      40   30           3          1   40   10
000034     100   90           4          2   80   10
```

...but I have not a single clue how to achieve this!

I would put it in a cube, but a) there is only a single table and no other references and b) I know almost nothing about cubes!

Comment: how can we know that points are negative or positive?

Comment: I know literally nothing about cubes, but it sounds like what you're looking for is just a cursor, is it not? I know everyone hates cursors, but that's the best way I know to compare consecutive rows without loading it down onto a client machine (which is obviously worse).

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL 2008 R2.
Points are always positive - I only have the "Points as of PointsDate" and I am trying to work out the changes.

Comment: Then how are you suming the value for neg

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Cursors may be the best way for this - its about 12.5Mn rows for about 12,000 customer ID's.  So can cursor it, set it off overnight and then find the results :)

Comment: @Azar If points on 10-MAR-2014 = 100 and points on next date for that customer = 50, then they have used 50 points, which is the equivalent of -50

Comment: So you want the differences per day? So using the Row_Number() over the partition of the customer Id, excluding the first transaction, and then joining against the total/MIN and MAX per customer will not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll copy my comment from above: I know literally nothing about cubes, but it sounds like what you're looking for is just a cursor, is it not? I know everyone hates cursors, but that's the best way I know to compare consecutive rows without loading it down onto a client machine (which is obviously worse).

I see you mentioned in your response to me that you'd be okay setting it off to run overnight, so if you're willing to accept that sort of performance, I definitely think a cursor will be the easiest and quickest to implement. If this is just something you do here or there, I'd definitely do that. It's nobody's favorite solution, but it'd get the job done.

Unfortunately, yeah, at twelve million records, you'll definitely want to spend some time optimizing your cursor. I work frequently with a database that's around that size, and I can only imagine how long it'd take. Although depending on your usage, you might want to filter based on user, in which case the cursor will be easier to write, and I doubt you'll be facing enough records to cause much of a problem. For instance, you could just look at the top twenty users and test their records, then do more as needed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be solved in regular TSQL with a common table expression that numbers the lines per customer, along with an outer self join that compares each row with the previous one;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT customerid, points, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY pointsdate) rn
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT cte.customerid, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN cte.points > old.points THEN cte.points - old.points ELSE 0 END) pos,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN cte.points < old.points THEN old.points - cte.points ELSE 0 END) neg,
  SUM(CASE WHEN cte.points > old.points THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Count(pos)],  
  SUM(CASE WHEN cte.points < old.points THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Count(neg)],
  MAX(cte.points) max, 
  MIN(cte.points) min
FROM cte
JOIN cte old
  ON cte.rn = old.rn + 1
 AND cte.customerid = old.customerid
GROUP BY cte.customerid
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b32cf/3).

The query would have been somewhat simplified using SQL Server 2012's more extensive analytic functions.

Answer (score 1):

An approach similar to the one of Joachim Isaksson, but with more work in the `CTE` and less on the main query

```
WITH A AS (
  SELECT c.CustomerID, c.Points, c.PointsDate
       , Diff = c.Points - l.Points
       , l.PointsDate lPointsDate
  FROM   Customer c
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                             Points, PointsDate
                      FROM   Customer cu
                      WHERE  c.CustomerID = cu.CustomerID
                        AND  c.PointsDate > cu.PointsDate
                      ORDER BY cu.PointsDate Desc) l
)
SELECT CustomerID
     , Pos = SUM(Diff * CAST(Sign(Diff) + 1 AS BIT))
     , Neg = SUM(Diff * (1 - CAST(Sign(Diff) + 1 AS BIT)))
     , [Count(pos)] = SUM(0 + CAST(Sign(Diff) + 1 AS BIT))
     , [Count(neg)] = SUM(1 - CAST(Sign(Diff) + 1 AS BIT))
     , Max(Points) [Max], Min(Points) [Min]
FROM   A
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16234/8)</kbd>

The condition that remove the first day is the `JOIN` (`CROSS APPLY`) in the `CTE`: the first day as no previous day, so is filtered out.

In the main query instead of using a `CASE` to filter the positive and negative difference I preferred the `SIGN` function:

- this function return -1 for negative, 0 for zero and +1 for positive
- shifting the value with `Sign(Diff) + 1` mean that the new return values are 0, 1 and 2
- the `CAST` to bit compress those to `0` for negative and `1` for zero or positive.

The `0 +` in the definition of the `[Count(pos)]` create a implicit conversion to an integer value as `BIT` cannot be summed.
The `1 -` to `SUM` and `COUNT` the negative difference is equivalent to a `NOT`: it invert the values of the `BIT SIGN` to 1 for negative and 0 for zero of positive.